# How many sequences of lenght n defined as {X1, X2,...., XN} , where X1, X2,..., XN are natrural numbers and X1<2, X2<X1+2, ..., XN<X(N-1)+2 are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have been struggling to find a formula for this question for a while I got stuck.

Here is what I tried doing:

I built an arbor with all the possible sequences until n = 4 and I defined NR(N) as the number of solutions for the length n and saw that NR(N) = NR(N-1) * 2 + X as you will see in the picture. The arbor looks like this:

[image]

Now, I don't know how to continue.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you work out the numbers $NR(n)$ for small $n$, you will find the Catalan numbers showing up, so you should probably look for a bijection with one of the many Catalan number interpretations. I think that Dyck paths are the easiest to relate to your sequences counted by $NR(n)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I didn't know what a Catalan number means so I searched it on the Wikipedia page. Here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number.

Comment: As it turns out, my question was actually the last example from the wikipedia page, but with the sequence starting from 0, not 1. You can see the example from the wikipedia page if you press ctrl + f and type this: "is the number of length n sequences that start with". So the NR(n) numbers are actually Catalan numbers!

Thanks again!